# Cyclic Polynomial Representation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$
I have seen an exercise as follows:

> A *cyclic permutation* of natural numbers $1, 2, \ldots, n$ is the permutation $12\cdots n$, or one of permutations $j(j + 1)\cdots n 1 2 \cdots (j - 1), j = 2, 3, \ldots, n$. If
> for every cyclic permutation $j(j + 1)\cdots n 1 2 \cdots (j - 1)$ of $1, 2, \ldots, n$, the polynomial $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ satisfy
> \begin{align*} 
> f(x_j, x_{j + 1}, \ldots, x_n, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{j - 1}) = f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n),  
> \end{align*}  where $j = 2, 3, \ldots, n$, then $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is called a *cyclic polynomial* of indeterminates $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$.  Prove, any real cyclic polynomial $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ can be expressed as a **real** polynomial of polynomials $g_j(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = x_1\eps^j  + x_2\eps^{2j} + \cdots + x_n\eps^{nj}, j = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1$, where $\eps$ is the primitive $n$th root of unity.

Without the requirement of **real** polynomial, any polynomial $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ can be expressed as a complex polynomial $h(g_0, g_1, \ldots, g_{n - 1})$, as $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ can be linearly expressed by $\{g_0, \ldots, g_{n - 1}\}$. While comes into the real polynomial,
I am not entirely sure if the conclusion is true and quite clueless about the proof. In fact, it is even difficult for me to express the cyclic polynomial $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2$ as a real polynomial of $g_0, g_1, g_2, g_3$. Any hints or solution would be greatly appreciated.

---

The conclusion of the question is wrong. For a counterexample, $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1x_2^2 + x_2x_3^2 + x_3x_1^2$ is a cyclic polynomial, when written in terms of $g_0, g_1, g_2$, the coefficient of $g_2^3$ is $\bar{\eps}$, which is not a real number.

Comment: Can you cite where is the problem taken from? Seems interesting.

Comment: @Phicar It's an exercise from a Chinese linear algebra textbook.